# Jquery with is(':visible') and Toggle

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle, visible

I have this html code

```
<div id="testb">This will have a blue background the background when the below text will have disappeared</div>
<input class="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login" />
</div>
<div id="testa">this text will disappear when I click the button</div>
```

and this jquery script

```
$('.loginButton').click(function (event) {
    $('#testa').toggle();
});

if ($('#testa').is(':visible')) {
    $("#testb").css("background-color", "red");
} else {
    $("#testa").css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

I want to change the color of the background to change depending if #testa is visible or not. I don't want to implement the code on the click event. It doesn't work, why?

Comment: "I don't want to implement the code on the click event"??? It does not work precisely because of this :) You must change "something" within the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery does not perform dynamic binding like this. Your if/else statement is evaluated one time (at run time), and that statement is not ever run again (unless its part of another block of code that is called multiple times).

The only way to do that is to actually evaluate the status of testa's visibility and then toggle your background.

Hate to tell you, but without an action, there can be no reaction. The onclick is the only way to do it.

I will suggest that you wrap that if/else in a function, and call that function:

```
$('.loginButton').click( function(event){
    $('#testa').toggle();  
    toggleBG(); 
});

function toggleBG{
    if($('#testa').is(':visible')) {
        $("#testb").css("background-color", "red"); 
    } else{
        $("#testa").css("background-color", "blue"); 
    }
}
```

For the record, you can do that in one line if you want to be compact:

```
$('.loginButton').click( function(event){
    $('#testa').toggle();  
    $("#testb").css("background-color", $('#testa').is(':visible') ? "red" : "blue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because you check `is(':visible')` at the first time when website load, only at that time.

if you need to check every time you click at it, you need to put `is(':visible')` inside toggle function

```
$('.loginButton').click( function(event){
    $('#testa').toggle(function() { 
        // this part will check everytime toggle load
        if($('#testa').is(':visible')) {
            $("#testb").css("background-color", "red"); 
        } else{
            $("#testa").css("background-color", "blue"); 
        }
    });   
});

// this will check at the first time
if($('#testa').is(':visible')) {
    $("#testb").css("background-color", "red"); 
} else{
    $("#testa").css("background-color", "blue"); 
}
```

Comment: @faf  If this answer your question, you can  [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)